# SQL search syntax for phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have the WordPress _posts table and a specific list of IDs (e.g. 100, 102, 137, 141, ...), what SQL code should I use in phpMyAdmin to have the combination ID 100 + post_title always of ID 100 and so on for IDs 102, 137, etc?

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, post_title
FROM wp_posts
WHERE ID IN (100, 102, 137, 141)
END;
```

This code will select only the posts with the specified IDs (100, 102, 137, 141) from the wp_posts table.